# Reshaping data where two rows relate to one ID variable

Tags: r, reshape2

I am relatively new to R and have searched the site, but can't seem to find the answer to my question and was hoping that someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a large data set of ~ 180 variables. One of these variables is a Child_ID and another is Parent_No. The data is currently formatted such that two rows could respond to the same Child_ID i.e. Child_ID =1 but Parent_No could = 1 or 2.  I need to format this such that one row refers to one Child_ID with both parents responses, such that the variables would be X_Parent1, X_Parent2, Y_Parent1, Y_Parent2 etc. In some instances there may only be one row for a particular Child_ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  child_ID  = c(1,1,2),
  parent_ID = c("X_Parent1", "X_Parent2", "X_Parent1"))

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parent_ID, values_from = parent_ID)
```